# Need to add a counter in php to separate the rows every 4 columns

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, row, counter

I have this code, and I need to close a row every 4 post. Every post is inside a div. I tried some things but I coudn't implement to my code.

```
    <?php
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    global $post;
    $all_events = tribe_get_events(
        array(
            'eventDisplay'=>'upcoming',
            //'posts_per_page'=>10,
    )
    );

    foreach($all_events as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="event-date"><?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post->ID, true, 'j M'); ?></span>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="event-thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="event-excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="event-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

<?php } //endforeach ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: So you essentially want a list that wraps every four entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    global $post;
    $all_events = tribe_get_events(
        array(
            'eventDisplay'=>'upcoming',
            //'posts_per_page'=>10,
    )
    );
      $count = 1;
    foreach($all_events as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="event-date"><?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post->ID, true, 'j M'); ?></span>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="event-thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="event-excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="event-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
<?php
 if($count == 4){
  echo "<div class='seperator'></div>";
  $count =1;
  }
 ?>
<?php $count++; } //endforeach ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually solve this 100% in CSS, so you don't need any counting or handling inside your PHP code.

Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/WC92e/).

`float: left` will cause the single elements to all follow each other (left aligned).
`clear: left` on every `4 * n + 1`-th element (`nth-child(4n+1)`) will clear this, essentially forcing a line break.

There is one caveat to this: If there's no room for all 4 entries in one row, you'll end up with additional wrapping, which can be avoided by defining a fixed `width` for the container.

---

A simplified in-code version for PHP would just count the fields written and add a line break as necessary:

```
$i = 1;                        // counter
foreach ($events as $event) {  // iterate over all events
    if ($i++ % 4 == 0)         // a % b will be 0 for 4, 8, etc.
        echo '<br />';         // print the line break using whatever HTML you see fit.
    print_event($event);       // print the actual event
}
```

You might ask whether I check for the line break before actually printing an event: That's to prevent additional line breaks if the number of entries is a multiple of 4, i.e. I avoid having an empty trailing line.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It works like this:

```
$i == 0;
foreach($some_array as $some_value){
    if ($i % $number_to_divide_by == 0) {
        // do something here every nth time
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but I have the problem with the implementation in my code.